# Java NullPointerException When try to recieve a JSON String from external web page

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to connect my android app to PHP page..
this is AsyncTask class function:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            accountDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",params[0]));

            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://site.page.php","POST",accountDetails);

           /*My Problem is here..*/
           String registerReport = json.getString("registerReport");
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            error = e.toString();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and my php page return this:

```
{"registerReport":"1"}
```

And then i got this error:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attemp to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Stringorg.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Comment: How I can get The registerReport value? @Zoe :c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attemp to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Stringorg.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

means that you are trying to call the getString() method on a null object.

In your specific case, your object called 'json' is null after this initialization :

> JSONObject json =
>   jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://site.page.php","POST",accountDetails);

To fix this error, you can try if your object is null before to call the  getString() method :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            accountDetails.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",params[0]));

            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://site.page.php","POST",accountDetails);

           if (json == null) {
               return null;
           }
           String registerReport = json.getString("registerReport");
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            error = e.toString();
        }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The Error gone but still i can't get the value of the registerReport, do you have any idea how to fix this? :(

Comment: because `jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://site.page.php","POST",accountDetails); ` returns a null object. Please check (in a browser for example) that your server (http://site.page.php) can respond to a POST method.

Comment: `$response = array();  $response["registerReport"] = "1"; echo json_encode($response); ` .. I'm Sure that the page is written property.